# Port forwarding with WCF vb.net TCP chat app

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, tcp, chat, portforwarding

I created a TCP chat app in Visual Basic C# by [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hv6-J7otz10) tutorial video, and my friend cant connect to the chat server because he is on an other network. How to fix this? I forwarded the ports, but if I enter not local IP address in App.config it crashes. I need help! I trying to fix this sciene 2 days but nothing, I found nothing about this.

The Server's App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<system.serviceModel> 
    <services>
        <service name="ProvinciaEZChatBySTEVEN_S.ChattingService">
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:9876/ChattingService"
                binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="ChattingServiceEndPoint"
                contract="ProvinciaEZChatBySTEVEN_Interfaces.IChattingService" />
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The Client's App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:9876/ChattingService"
            binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="ProvinciaEZChatBySTEVEN_Interfaces.IChattingService"
            name="ChattingServiceEndPoint" kind="" endpointConfiguration="" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please add your code and specifically what you have tried.

Comment: The code of what? The App.config? I'm waiting for your awnser and I'll give the code of App.config.

Comment: If your friend is on another computer, then client app.config must be changed to refer to your IP address, not `localhost`.

Comment: We are on other network;I'm in Hungary and he is in Slovakia.